# Как установить значение переменной в атрибут src тега img в Django

Tags: django

Нужно загрузить картинки. url`ы для картинок содержатся в элементах list new_products. Необходимо в каждый тег  в атрибут src добавить url.

views.py:

```
def new_products(request):
  new_products = [{name: 'Product1', 'url_image': 'blog\\images\\image1.jpg'},
  {name: 'Product2', 'url_image': 'blog\\images\\image2.jpg'}
  ]
  return render(request, 'blog/new_products.html', {'new_products': new_products})
```

И есть шаблон new_products.html:

```
<div>
    {% load static %}

    <main class="content">
            <h3>Продукция</h3>
            {% for product in new_products %}
            <div class="product-image">
                <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                <img src="{% static "{{product.url_image}}" %}">
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </main>
</div>
```

Переменная product.url_image не обрабатывается как переменная, а вставляется как текст "`/static/...element.url_image`", вообщем вместо значения переменной её название. Имеются ли какие-то встроенные возможности Jinja2 записать в атрибут тега значение переменной или придется писать скрипт на *JavaScript*?

Comment: Во-первых, про какой всё-таки шаблонизатор вы спрашиваете - django или jinja2? Во-вторых, `static` для статики. В-третьих, что именно у вас в `element`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev первое - значит попутал, отредактирую, второе - static для того чтобы файлы картинок включались, разве, это не ясно? третье - на самом деле не важно что в element, там все правильно, а если вам это так нужно, то element = {url_image: '...', .....}, но какая разница, что в там, если в атрибуте src все равно записыватеся "/static/%7B%7Belement.url_image%7D%7D", то есть чтобы не было в переменной, оно не записывается.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev картинки подключаются, елси вписывать их урлы вручную, дак почему неправильно использую тег static`то? Если неправильно, тогда как правильно?

Comment: В Jinja2, если мне не изменяет память, вообще нет такого тега. И загрузка с помощью `load` не делается.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev зато  есть в django, потому-то я и добавлял тег django, а вы меня сбили..

Comment: @SonicMyst а Jinja2 тогда при чём?

Comment: Ну то есть jinja2 всё-таки ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal почему не причем, {% static product.url_image %} - это не синтаксис используемый в jinja2? Если не причемЮ тогда что "причем"? Обозначьте.

Comment: Нет, это не синтаксис jinja2. Он всего лишь *похож* на jinja2, но это не он. А вообще исторически всё наоборот: это синтаксис jinja2 похож на синтаксис шаблонизатора Django, потому что разработчики jinja2 вдохновлялись именно джангой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением оказалось то, что надо было убрать фигурные скобки радом с переменной.

Было:

```
<img src="{% static "{{product.url_image}}" %}">
```

Стало:

```
<img src="{% static product.url_image %}">
```